# The strangest render bug

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This is happening with *every* project:

The render is randomly bugging on certain frames.
It seems to only happen to objects with complex geometry.

Any hints on what could be causing the issue? Does it have anything to do with "Persistent Data" being turned on?

[image]

Comment: Without more details, I can't tell what you mean by "bugging". All three images look like deliberate renders to me. What are you expecting, why are you expecting it, and what's not meeting your expectations?

Comment: have you turned on Depth of Field or Motion Blur? Maybe it comes from one of those?